# Haskell replace specific characthers of a string

Tags: haskell

I've just started to learn haskell so this might be a really simple question..but here it is:
I have a string, a charachter C and a number N. I need to write a function that replaces all the characthers from the position of the string that are divided by N with characther C. 
I must use list comprehension and only Base Function or Library function.

```
 replace::Char->Int->String->String
```

Can someone please help me?

```
replace :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
replace y xs = [ if isDivided i then y else x | (i,x) <- zip [0..] xs ]
```

Comment: Be more specific. "Can someone help me" is a yes/no question.

Comment: well, i need to write this function but I don't even know from where to start. I've specifed that I've just started to learn haskell :)

Comment: So you want someone to teach you Haskell from scratch? That's too broad for SO.

Comment: I don't expect someone to teach me from scratch..I asked this question in order to find a start point..I know a few things, but i don't have any idea about this one.

Comment: Do you know how to check whether `x` is divisible by `y`? Do you know how list comprehensions work?

Comment: I wrote a function that checks if a number is isdivided  and replace it, but it;s for int..it's not for a string

Comment: What's `isDivided`?

Comment: I suppose that i should write another function that check if a number is divisible by n, I'm trying to figure it how, until then..i ve just call it. Hope I didn't said something stupid :)

Comment: isDivisible I think I can replace with  x `rem` N == 0

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is basically correct. If you change the type signature:

```
replace :: Char -> Int -> String -> String
```

and add another argument:

```
replace y d xs = [ if isDivisible i d then y else x | (i,x) <- zip [0..] xs ]
```

then you're almost done. You just have to write `isDivisible`.